# Disappearing arrow head in tikz graphs

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, graphs

I am drawing directed acyclic graphs in tikz. They look great, but when i try to specify arrow input coordinates sometimes the arrow head disappears, and I would like to understand why.

my preamble is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{listings}
%load options
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc, shapes.geometric, shapes.multipart,
        shapes, arrows.meta, arrows, decorations.markings, external, trees}

%Create custom arrow style:
\tikzstyle{Arrow} = [
thick,
decoration={
markings,
mark=at position 1 with {
\arrow[thick]{latex}
}
},
shorten >= 3pt, preaction = {decorate}
]
```

And when I use the following code all of the arrow head on the edge from c-->Y shows up:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (1) {};
    \node [right =of 1] (2)  {E};
    \node [right =of 2] (3) {};
    \node [right =of 3] (4) {Y};
    \node [left =of 1] (5) {C};
    \node [above =of 3] (6) {M};

    \draw[Arrow] (2.east)--(4.west);
    \draw[Arrow] (2) to (6);
    \draw[Arrow] (6) to (4);
    \draw[Arrow] (5) to [out=-25, in=-160] (4);
    \draw[Arrow] (5) to (6);
    \draw[Arrow] (5.east)--(2.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}
\end{figure}
```

[image: normal looking directed acyclic graph]

however, when i change `\draw[Arrow] (5) to [out=-25, in=-160]`  to `\draw[Arrow] (5) to [out=-25, in=-122]`  the arrow head disappears:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (1) {};
    \node [right =of 1] (2)  {E};
    \node [right =of 2] (3) {};
    \node [right =of 3] (4) {Y};
    \node [left =of 1] (5) {C};
    \node [above =of 3] (6) {M};

    \draw[Arrow] (2.east)--(4.west);
    \draw[Arrow] (2) to (6);
    \draw[Arrow] (6) to (4);
    \draw[Arrow] (5) to [out=-25, in=-122] (4);
    \draw[Arrow] (5) to (6);
    \draw[Arrow] (5.east)--(2.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}
\end{figure}
```

[image: directed acyclic graph with missing arrow head]

This is a simple example of an issue I have been having in general, which is confounding my ability to precisely control more complex graphs. Can someone suggest why this is happening and a potential way to address it?

Comment: When the arrows are drawn with `->` it works. It seems to be a rounding issue with `markings, mark=at position 1 ...`. If you use `mark=at position .999` it works.

Comment: perfect, thanks!

Comment: This should probably be filed as issue to the package.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the `markings` decoration instead of a normal arrow tip?

Comment: I like the way it looks

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use the `markings` library, especially not for an arrow tip that's at the tip of a path. That's already built into PGF/TikZ with a lot of customization options when using the current [`arrows.meta` library](https://tikz.dev/tikz-arrows) (which uses capitalized Arrow Tip names in contrast to the deprecated options).

With just a simple `-Latex[scale=.8]` you can adjust the size so that it looks like your output but actually places an arrow tip at the end without having to guesstimate any values.

---

I've added the same diagram produced by the `tikzcd` environment provided by the `cd` library. It uses different distances between the nodes but they can be adjusted by using `column sep`/`row sep` and different `inner sep`s. (Though, your empty nodes `1` and `3` are not present in the `tikzcd` example.)

The first diagram also has optional settings provided by the `cd` library which might be useful for nodes that have more varied content with different heights and depths.

---

For curved paths, it might be a good idea to load the `bending` library (which already sets `arrows=[flex]`) but also applying `arrows=[bend]` for nice arrow tips on those paths.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, cd, decorations.markings, positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  % this might be useful for more varied content:
%  nodes=asymmetrical rectangle, commutative diagrams/center yshift=.75ex,
  Arrow/.style={thick, -{Latex[scale=.8]}},
]
\node (1) {};
\node [right=of 1] (2) {E};
\node [right=of 2] (3) {};
\node [right=of 3] (4) {Y};
\node [left =of 1] (5) {C};
\node [above=of 3] (6) {M};

\path[Arrow] (2) edge (4) edge (6)
             (6) edge (4)
             (5) edge[out=-25, in=-122] (4)
                 edge (6) edge (2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[Arrow/.style={
  thick, shorten >= 3pt, preaction = decorate,
  decoration={name=markings, mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[thick]{latex}}}}]
\node              (1) {};
\node [right=of 1] (2) {E};
\node [right=of 2] (3) {};
\node [right=of 3] (4) {Y};
\node [left =of 1] (5) {C};
\node [above=of 3] (6) {M};

\draw[Arrow] (2.east)--(4.west);
\draw[Arrow] (2) to (6);
\draw[Arrow] (6) to (4);
\draw[Arrow] (5) to [out=-25, in=-122] (4);
\draw[Arrow] (5) to (6);
\draw[Arrow] (5.east)--(2.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzcd}[
  arrow style=tikz, >={Latex[scale=.8]},
  arrows=thick, math mode=false, center yshift=+.75ex]
 & & & M \ar[dr] \\
C \ar[rr] \ar[rrru] \ar[rrrr, out=-25, in=-122] 
 & & E \ar[ru] \ar[rr]
     & & Y
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]

---

[image]